# php escape character need back slash to stay after escape

Tags: php

i am trying to escape back slash in my code but how ever i try it doesn't work

here's my code without back slash

```
<?php
echo ("<a href=\."http://www.example.com">Home</a> &raquo; ");
  for ($i = 1; $i < count($parts); $i++)
    {
    if (!strstr($parts[$i],"."))
      {
      echo("<a href="");
      for ($j = 0; $j <= $i; $j++) {echo $parts[$j]."/";};
      echo("">". str_replace('-', ' ', $Pages[$parts[$i]])."</a> &raquo; ");
      }
    else
?>
```

i need it to be like this after escape

```
<?php
echo ("<a href=\"http://www.example.com\">Home</a> &raquo; ");
    for ($i = 1; $i < count($parts); $i++)
        {
        if (!strstr($parts[$i],"."))
            {
            echo("<a href=\"");
            for ($j = 0; $j <= $i; $j++) {echo $parts[$j]."/";};
            echo("\">". str_replace('-', ' ', $Pages[$parts[$i]])."</a> &raquo; ");
            }
        else
?>
```

this the parts that i want to escape `<a href=\"` and `echo("<a href=\"");` and `echo("\">".` i need back slash to be exist there after escape

Comment: It is unclear what you actually want to achieve, since you say nothing about your motivation for this strange task. The nature of your issue suggests that you lack knowledge of some language feature which you try to emulate. Don't get that wrong, we all lack knowledge, we all started, we all learn. But if you tell us a but _why_ you try to implement such escaping strategy, then we might be able to point you to some easier solution.

Comment: escaping is a pain, and makes for code that is almost unreadable, and definitely unmaintainable.

Comment: Instead use this idea... `echo '<a href="">';` see how much more readable that is. wrap the whole string with one kind of quote and use the other kind of quote inside that wrapping. Its basically what @JayBlanchard was saying in his answer

Comment: PS: `echo` does not need braces

Comment: *Talk amongst yourselves* I see. ^ and `v < edit:` which was deleted.

Comment: voting to close

Comment: agree with you, escaping is pain really @RiggsFolly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need echo

<a href=\"

just add "\\" for single "\" in result output.

echo("<a href=\\\"");

Comment: perfect. that is wierd none answerd this unless they understand from you. what i mean is thank you :D